# How does encoding and decoding functions work in Swift 3 using NSCoding?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Good afternoon!

Can anyone help me understand how saving data using `NSCoding` works in Swift? I am a beginner in this language and I am currently watching some tutorials on how to work with table views(create cells, saving data, etc).

The code below creates a `UITableView` where I can just add the first and last name of an employee. However, I cannot understand how these encoding and decoding functions work, because it has been assigned just one key to the first name and one key to the last name(that's what I understood). I mean that, because it is an array of employees, and is these functions intelligent enough to give the same keys to the first and last names of all the employees and then to retrieve the data?

**ViewController class:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var data = [Employee]()

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadData()
    }

    var filePath: String {
        let manager = FileManager.default 
        let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        return url!.appendingPathComponent("Data").path
    }

    private func loadData(){ //Decode
        if let ourData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [Employee] {
            data = ourData
        }
    }

    private func saveData(employee: Employee){ //Encode
        self.data.append(employee)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: filePath)
    }

    func numberOfSections(...)

    func tableView(...)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Could be UITableViewCell(), but for a better performance we use this reusable form below:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        //"indexPath" will return the information based on the number of rows we have. The number of rows in this case is "data.count"
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].Name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].LastName

        return cell

    }

    @IBAction func addEmployee(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Employee", message: "Enter Employee's name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveButon = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default){
            (alertAction: UIAlertAction) in

            let employeeName = alert.textFields?[0].text!
            let employeeLastName = alert.textFields?[1].text!

            let newEmployee = Employee(name: employeeName!, lastName: employeeLastName!)

            self.saveData(employee: newEmployee)

            self.myTableView.reloadData()

        }

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)

        alert.addAction(saveButon)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)    
    }
}
```

Employee class image:

[image: code image]

I hope you understood my questions, otherwise let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: It serializes and de-serializes your object models so it can be stored to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The keys are what the coder uses to serialize and deserialize the properties of your class.  You can give them any string value.  You could call the firstName property key "firstName" if you like instead of "name" but they have to match the value of when you code and decode the object.  If they do not you will not get the values you expect.  The class has to match as well to the class being decoded and encoded so beware of changing this in the future or you will have a crash.  The data will absolutely persist between launches. The data is stored in the app file directory. Here is a link to a project that uses the exact code above.  You can see for yourself that it will persist between launches.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zuxd1kt3brkxtgi/Archiving.zip?dl=0